# Audio file not playing In html

Tags: javascript, html, audio

So I made a website that was supposed to redirect the person to another website where they were going to be rickrolled. The GIF of Rick worked fine, but for some reason, I just can't get the audio file to play. Redirecting to the new website works fine and there are no problems with that.

```js
let audioo = document.getElementById("audi");
audi.play();
console.log("audio funksjonen kjører");
```

```html
<audio id="audi" src="./RickRoll.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

I tried to use the `autoplay` attribute in the audio tag, but that did not work. The mp3 file is in the same folder as the HTML and CSS files, so I don't think the program doesn't see the mp3 file.

Comment: browsers usually won't play audio without user interaction - is there any useful information in the browser *developer* tools console

Comment: I use safari, and the only error msg I got in console is this:

Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

Comment: There is nothing you can do about it for obvious security reasons. If you could bypass or overwrite user settings then it would pose a huge security issue.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rickroll Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Audio element -->
  <audio id="audi" src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3"></audio>

  <!-- Button to trigger audio play -->
  <button onclick="playAudio()">Play Audio</button>

  <script>
    function playAudio() {
      var audio = document.getElementById("audi");
      audio.play();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In your code, the autoplay attribute in the  tag may not work due to these policies. To comply with browser restrictions and ensure that your audio plays, it's recommended to initiate media playback as a response to a user action such as clicking a button.

Comment: Many browsers won’t play audio without some interaction from the user eg a click. Best to try the code you suggest as an answer.

Comment: If it would have been purely typo-caused, you should have not answered but flagged as `Not reproducible or caused by typos` instead

Comment: @AHaworth You are right and Thanks for the information appreciate that.

Comment: Is there not any possibility that the audio gets played when I enter the browser automatically, because if the person has to click a button it kinda ruins the whole point of the website. This is the only error msg I got in inspect element console. I use safari btw, I don't know if that's relevant. Error msg: Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

Answer (score -1):

First you have a typo mistake 'audi.play()' should be 'audioo.play'
why don't you try this

```html
<audio id="Audi">
  <source src="./RickRoll.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

```js
<script>
    let audioo = document.getElementById("audi");
    audioo.play();
</script>
```

Comment: Many browsers won’t play audio without some interaction from the user eg a click. Best to try the code you suggest as an answer.

Comment: If it would have been purely typo-caused, you should have not answered but flagged as `Not reproducible or caused by typos` instead. Using the source tag instead of the attribute makes no difference.